# Can I add selector to a different class?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am creating a custom navigation button, instead of it's default appearance. I am able to create the button, but what I am having trouble with is its selector. I want to add selector of that button in a method of different class. I pass the UIViewController as a parameter so I can modify the navigationBar.

```
-(void)addNavButton:(MyViewController *)vc
{
    UIImage *buttonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImg.size.width, buttonImg.size.height);

    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(vc.popBackNavigation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];  //Here is the line where I am having trouble

    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
}
```

I am doing this because I don't want to add the same methods in each class to define a customNavigation item. If there is a short way or efficient way to do this please let me know

Comment: Replace `@selector(vc.popBackNavigation)` with `@selector(popBackNavigation)` and change the target from `self` to `vc`.

Comment: @GuyKogus I am sorry I didn't get it correctly before, now that I see it clear I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target a different class in this case.

Remember, the target is the object you want to send the message to. So in this scenario, the selector is:

```
@selector(popBackNavigation)
```

and the target is the `vc`.

Giving:

```
[button addTarget:vc action:@selector(popBackNavigation) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for something like this:

```
@implementation Utility

+ (UIBarButtonItem *)addNavButton:(id)target withSelector:(SEL)selectorMethod
{
    UIImage *buttonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImg.size.width, buttonImg.size.height);
    [button addTarget:target action:selectorMethod forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];      
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];

    return customBarItem;
}

@end
```

call this method from you viewController,

```
@implementation Mycontroller

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   UIBarButtonItem *leftItem = [Utility addNavButton:self withSelector:@selector(backbuttonAction)];
   self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftItem;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customise this back button across your app you can put this code in your `AppDelegate`

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)options
{
 UIImage *buttonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];

 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage:buttonImg  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
 // customize the position if needed
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, buttonImg.size.height*2) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 return yes;
}
```

Without any further interaction this will overwrite the default back button style for your app.

Comment: This is working in a kind of way, but there's a problem with customization because I can't show my custom view, but I can add only a background image

Comment: Well your customView is just a UIButton of type custom with frame taht equals to the frame of your image. There is no need of creating UIButton and adding it to UIBarButtonItem. Anyways you're free to take the approach that suits you best. Happy coding man

Comment: Yes but I had to remove also the title. It was a great method to do my job, but I saw another post referring to this method, and pointed out that this wasn't an efficient way. Thnx for your reply anyway.